# The type org.hibernate.LockMode cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, hibernate, templates

when I'm writing DAO code for deleting emp object, I'm getting this error. since I'm a newbie to this hibernate I'm finding difficult to crack this one out. please give your valuable suggestion.[I've attached my coding image below]

thanks in advance :)

```
 package sa.java8.spring.hibernate;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class EmployeeDAO {
    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp ) {
        template.save(emp);
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp) {
        template.delete(emp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share code. Not images of the code..

Comment: @SarvanKumar I've edited my post sir... deleting part gives me the trouble. thank you :)

Comment: The stacktrace would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate core jar is missing from your classpath.

if maven project add following dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Other versions can be found here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core